# Linq lambda not working but delegate does

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, delegates

OK, this is doing my head in - I'm not even sure how to search for this.

Here is the first part of my function:

```
var rules = context.Rules.Include(r => r.CreatedBy).Include(r => r.ModifiedBy);

IUserManager um = GetUserManager();
var currentUser = um.GetCurrent();
```

Can someone tell me why this works:

```
return rules.Where(delegate(Rule r)
{
    return r.CreatedBy.CompanyID == currentUser.CompanyID;
});
```

but this doesn't:

```
return rules.Where(r => r.CreatedBy.CompanyID == currentUser.CompanyID);
```

- It's EF Code first and CreatedBy and ModifiedBy are both virtual properties.
- r.CreatedBy and currentUser are both instances of the same class (if you didn't already work this out)
- What the second snippet is returning is an empty list.  It's as though the eager loading isn't working and the lambda doesn't cause a lazy load.

Note:  I've just discovered that if I change the first line to

```
var rules = context.Rules.Include(r => r.CreatedBy)
    .Include(r => r.ModifiedBy).ToList()
```

then the lambda works.  The question still stands though.  Why to I have to use the ToList() or the delegate.  I'm doing the same thing elsewhere in the same class and it works as I'd expect.

Thanks

Comment: They will behave quite differently, the first will call `Enumerable.Where(Func<Rule, bool>)` so it will fetch all records and filter them in memory. The second will try to create an sql query and execute that on the server. You'll have to look at the generated SQL to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: also, remember that `.ToList()` will actually fire the query and return results.  Execution is deferred until results are actually requested.

Comment: What is the signature for the function, what does it say you have to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because lambdas can be implicitly converted to delegates *or to expression trees*.  In the first case, the delegate is converted to an expression tree because `rules` is `IQueryable<>` and overload resolution chooses `Queryable.Where`.  When you use the anonymous function, however, that can't be converted to an expression tree, so overload resolution has to choose `Enumerable.Where`.

When you make rules into a `List<>`, that forces overload resolution to choose `Enumerable.Where`, because `List<>` does not implement `IQueryable<>`.  You could use `AsEnumerable()` to achieve the same effect without the overhead of creating the list.

As to why this doesn't work when you're "doing the same thing elsewhere in the same class and it works as I'd expect," we might be able to help if you give an example of code that does work.

Comment: What you've said doesn't explain what I'm seeing, but you gave me the clue I needed to fix the issue.

IQueryable expressions are calculated on the server side, in SQL in this case.  For a certain class of user in my system CompanyID can be null, so I'm storing the id in an int? in my class.

So, I've taken out the ToList() and change the lambda to 
return: 'rules.Where(r => (!r.CreatedBy.CompanyID.HasValue && !currentUser.CompanyID.HasValue) || (r.CreatedBy.CompanyID == currentUser.CompanyID));'
and it works!

Comment: Needless to say, the other example where my code works are comparing int and not int?  Marked your reply as the answer because turned the lightbulb in my head on.  Thank you.